# Statistics on Multisig Bitcoin Accounts by type of multisig

Tags: multi-signature

I am looking for statistics on Bitcoin addresses in use by number of multisig addresses.  Specifically, I would like to know how many accounts exist that use 1 of 1, 1 of 2, 2 of 2, etc.  Is there a place where this information exists?

Ideally, it would be nice if there was a threshold for amount of bitcoin associated with the address that could be set.

I would like to see something like https://www.coindesk.com/year-multisig-so-far or https://medium.com/@alcio/some-stats-about-bitcoin-multisig-915f0787ef2f, except these are rather old and they are measures of transactions and not used addresses.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such data source as far as I'm aware.

Moreover, you'll never be able to get complete stats on this, as a multisig address is not revealed to be multisig until an output is spent. If an address has only inputs, it can be any form of P2SH address (even segwit).

That said, for addresses that have been used to make outgoing transactions, you could use bitcoind and parse the raw blocks to appropriate scripts. It shouldn't be too hard to build.

Answer (score 0):

The site [p2sh.info](https://p2sh.info/dashboard/db/p2sh-repartition-by-type) somewhat covers what you are searching for.